# How to upload a list of files (automation) to FTP server?

Tags: automation, ftp, upload, client-server, sftp

I have a text (.txt) file that contains a list of files changed or added recently that need to be uploaded to live server. Manually browsing through different folders and selecting files to upload takes time and error prone.

Is there any **FTP client** that have **this feature** already, I will just **upload the .txt file** and it will **do its job**. Obviously I will previously have connection and folder synchronization enabled.

So far, I found a scripting solution for WinScp client, but I am looking for a client with feature to do just that, no scripting myself.

Comment: If you are looking for a GUI solution, you are a wrong site. This is a programing Q&A. Also FTP and SFTP are different protocol, make sure you understand which one you need to use.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl If you say wrong site then there is nothing much to say, but I think I have seen GUI related Q&A in this website, just don't have the links to give to you now. And I want GUI solution as I have already mentioned that implicitly in the question description

Answer (score -1):

You can use python pysftp library

https://pypi.org/project/pysftp/